# Cancel store.remove after server call in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs

I'm using ExtJS 4 and have an Ext.data.Store with an ajax proxy and api:

```
var gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'myurl',
            create: 'myurl',
            update: 'myurl',
            destroy: 'myurl'
        },
        reader: {
             type: 'json',
             successProperty: 'success',
             root: 'data',
             messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
             type: 'json',
             writeAllFields: false,
             root: 'data'
        },
        listeners: {
             exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                 Ext.MessageBox.show({
                     title: 'Server error',
                     msg: operation.getError(),
                     icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                     buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                 });
             }
        }
    ...
```

When I use the update function and my server returns a json object with `success:false` (because he entered something wrong) the field in my associated grid is still marked as changed and the user has the option to change his wrong value.

That works fine.

But when I remove a record from the store...

```
var store = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('gridStore');
store.remove(store.getById(id));
```

...then ExtJS removes this record from the store first and call the ajax api afterwards. So when the destroy api returns `success:false` the message is shown as exception like in the update api, thats fine, but my record has been removed from the store! As example the exception from the server says that you cannot remove this record because of whatever but it's already removed in the store.

How to cancel the store removement after the server sync? I want the record to stay in the store if the server returns `success:false`.

Any idea? Maybe a bug?

---

UPDATE **SOLUTION**

Based on Ryan's anwer, I modified the exception listener as following, which works very well:

```
 listeners: {
     exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
         Ext.MessageBox.show(...);
         // get the removed records and insert them where they have been
         var removedRecords = gridStore.getRemovedRecords();
         for(var i=0; i<removedRecords.length; i++){
             var record = removedRecords[i];
             gridStore.insert(record.index, record);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Probably a bug, or need to dig into the source code to see what happens. Hmm. Interesting question. Saw this before, but I overcome this by reloading the store. Inefficient but it's fine for small data.

Comment: Nice one :) But you forgot to add `gridStore.removed = []` else if you remove that item again you will have duplicates (then it's still in the removed array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just extending the code you gave, specifically the `listeners` area:

```
    listeners: {
         exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
             Ext.MessageBox.show({
                 title: 'Server error',
                 msg: operation.getError(),
                 icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                 buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
             });
             gridStore.add(gridStore.getRemovedRecords());
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that's the correct way. I changed your solution a little bit, have a look at my updated questions, because if you just add the records, they are added to the end of the list but they should stay where they have been before.

Answer (score 6):

The insert technique didn't work for me, the removed record stays marked for removal on the next sync operation. I am using `Ext.data.Store.rejectChanges()` for this purpose.

Comment: That's no default method is it? Did yo use [this implementation](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141982-commitChanges-and-rejectChanges-for-the-Store-in-ExtJS-4)?

Comment: That method exists in ExtJS 4.1.1a.  Not sure about 4.0 or versions in between.  This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am useing callback functions 'success','failure' or 'callback' when sync.
I hope this method can help you.

```
store.remove(records);
store.sync({ 
    success: function (proxy, operations) {
        // pop success message
    }, failure: function (proxy, operations) {
        // resume records
        store.rejectChanges();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using model.destroy, this is what i use for deleting singular entries from grid:

```
                text : 'Delete',
                itemId : 'delete',
                scope : this,
                handler : function() {
                    var selection = grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                    if(selection) {
                        selection.destroy({
                            failure : function() {
                                console.log('Record could not be deleted.');
                            },
                            success : function() {
                                store.remove(selection);
                                console.log('Record successfuly removed.');
                            },

                        });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: nice. suitable for single record only.