# ExtJS 4.2.1 - reject changes in store after getting error from server

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

In my application I'm deleting records using this code:

```
//try to delete item
s.eventStore.remove(s.ctx.rec);
//error handling
s.eventStore.getProxy().on({
    exception: function() {
        s.eventStore.rejectChanges();
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title: 'Server error',
            msg: 'data restored',
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
        });
    }
});
```

**This works fine**, but I would like to avoid adding listeners in every place, instead I would like to add one listener in my store.
I've tried modifying my store like this:

```
Ext.define('Urlopy.Store.Holidays', {
    extend: "Sch.data.EventStore",
    autoLoad: false,//zmiana
    autoSync: true,
    batch: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        pageParam: false, //to remove param "page"
        startParam: false, //to remove param "start"
        limitParam: false, //to remove param "limit"
        noCache: false, //to remove param "_dc"
        url: window.appUrl + 'api/Holidays',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function (store, response, operation) {
                    var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                        title: 'Server error',
                        msg: data.Message,
                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                    });
                    store.rejectChanges();
            }
        }
    },
    model: 'Urlopy.Model.Holiday'
});
```

This is basically same listener, but when I try to rejectChanges I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'rejectChanges'
```

How can I modify my store to have global exception handling and restore events if something goes wrong on server?

I don't want to use solution from [Cancel store.remove after server call in ExtJS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870691/cancel-store-remove-after-server-call-in-extjs-4) (store.add(store.getRemovedRecords());)

**EDIT:**

I've updated my stode definition to this:

```
Ext.define('Urlopy.Store.Holidays', {
    extend: "Sch.data.EventStore",
    autoLoad: false,
    autoSync: true,
    batch: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        pageParam: false, //to remove param "page"
        startParam: false, //to remove param "start"
        limitParam: false, //to remove param "limit"
        noCache: false, //to remove param "_dc"
        url: window.appUrl + 'api/Holidays',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation) {

                console.log(this);
                this.rejectChanges();
            },
            scope: this
        }
    },
    model: 'Urlopy.Model.Holiday'
});
```

but still I get same error and console outputs Window object instead of store.

Answer (score 3):

What about [rejecting](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-reject) each [record of the operation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Operation-method-getRecords), like this ?

```
listeners: {
  exception: function(proxy, request, operation, eOpts){
    // ... any user notification ...

    Ext.each(operation.getRecords(), function(record){
      record.reject();
    });
  }
}
```

PS: This is valid for ExtJS 5.x as well (inside Base Model will be generally available for entire application) !

Answer (score 1):

This should be addressed from the controller. If the call to a sync method fails it will trigger an failure callback where you can reject changes.

```
store.sync({
  failure : function(){
     store.rejectChanges();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the signature of the exception event is:

```
exception( this, response, operation, eOpts )
```

where `this` is the proxy. you need to add a scope:

```
listeners: {
    exception: function (proxy, response, operation) {
        var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title: 'Server error',
            msg: data.Message,
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
        });
        this.rejectChanges();
    },
    scope: this
}
```

It should work and in `this` should be the store.

Comment: Unfortunately I doesn't work. I changed listener as You suggested but I still get same exception. I tried adding `console.log(this);` before `this.rejectChanges();` and in console I get 'Window' instead of store.

Comment: I have listeners added to proxy, maybe this has something to do with this error?

Comment: only the proxy has the exception event. so its the right place. try to log `operation` maybe there is a reference to the store.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't there. I checked `proxy`, `response` and `operation`. There must be a way to do this.

Comment: ok, I give up, you could give the store an ID and set this ID as extra config param of the proxy and use `Ext.getStore()` to get the store...

Comment: I was thinking about same thing, but I would like to avoid querying StoreManager. I asked same question on sencha forum, maybe ExtJS devs will give me an answer

Comment: I think the reason for this problem is, that you could have a proxy not bind to a store, so why should there be a reference to it...

Answer (score 0):

new idea:

you could destroy the record directly and `model.destroy()` has an `operation` parameter where you can add a `failure` function.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your stores proxy add a listener for the exception. below is an example that on exception grabs the response msg and populates a pop up and rejects the changes.

```
     listeners: {
             exception: function (proxy, response, operation, eOpts){
                 var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                 Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', 'The proxy event failed: <br><li>'+data.errorMessage+'</li>');
                 Ext.each(operation.getRecords(), function(record){
                     record.reject();
                 });
             }
         }
```